# how to write the results of a stored procedure into an excel file with python

Tags: python, sql-server, excel, pycharm

I am recently new to Python and I was working in a piece of code that could connect to one of my databases to fetch for all the rows and columns, hence I would be able to hold that data into a list and then write it onto an Excel file. Here's the piece of code I wrote:

```
#create the MSSQL connection with python
table_one_connection = pypyodbc.connect(driver="{SQL Server}", server="xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx", uid="you-cant-see-me", pwd="guessme",Trusted_Connection = "No")

table_one_connection_results = []
row_table_one = 0

#set the cursor for table_one
cursor = table_one_connection.cursor()
cursor.execute("[data].[Tableschema].[DEFINED_SP] @start_date='xx-xx-xx', @end_date='xx-xx-xx'")

#get all the rows from the SP
results = cursor.fetchall()

#append the results into a list 
for index, result in enumerate(results):
    table_one_connection_results.append(result)

#start writing the results into an Excel file
results_workbook = xlwt.Workbook()
results_sheet    = results_workbook.add_sheet("SP values")

#insert the list results into the Excel file 
for index, value in enumerate(table_one_connection_results):
    results_sheet.write(row_table_one,0,value)
    row_table_one = row_table_one + 1

#write the workbook
results_workbook.save("C:\\Users\\UserX\\Desktop\\E\\output\\export_results.xls")
```

Now, the problem comes when the code is trying to write the data onto the Excel file, the computer displays the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): 
    line 284 in __rich_text_helper
    raise Exception ("Unexpected data type %r" % type(data))
    Exception: Unexpected data type <class 'float'>
```

Now, I am concerned that I am writing the data in column 1 (column A in Excel) and I tried to iterate each list item to write them in separate rows, however, I believe this is not the correct solution I desire but instead I would like to see each list item separated in different columns and different rows, something like this:

```
column A   column B   column C

value_one  value_two  value_three
```

instead of

```
column A
value_one,    value_two,    value_three
new_value_one new_value_two new_value_three
```

My main questions are:

1. Why did I receive this **Exception error of Unexpected data type** ?
2. I want to have each list item separated into different columns and different rows. How can I achieve this? Bonus: Is there a better approach to achieve this goal without using a list? What about a dictionary? Is this possible?

Thanks in advance, please edit or comment or ask for further details.

All answers are welcome!

### Update

Thanks to the comment of stovfl, I was able to determine that the directory did not exist, so I just updated it to a new value. This solves question one but now another problem arose: when I try to write in the workbook it says that I every line has an error, something like this:

```
Error in line 61418
data=('04/05/2017', 'xxxx', 'xxxxx', 'xxxxx', 100.0, 99.03, 99.15, 4.73)
```

The new question is, why I cannot write into the Excel workbook.

Comment: Just a guess. In your `for index, value in ...`, `value` looks like it's a tuple (or some other collection). You may not be able to write a tuple to Excel directly. What if you write one value at a time from the collection?

Comment: How can I achieve this? I was now examining this result and I was thinking in storing the results from the query into other data structure so I can easily enumerate and write it onto the Excel file.

Comment: In your `for` loop you would first unpack the tuple with something like `v0, v1, ..., vn = value`. (Replace v0...vn with more meaningful names). Then write each one to Excel with something like `results_sheet.write(row_table_one, 8, v4)` to put v4 in column 8 of the spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some tests and workarounds, I found a solution to my problem.

```
#create the MSSQL connection with python
table_one_connection = pypyodbc.connect(driver="{SQL Server}", server="xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx", uid="you-cant-see-me", pwd="guessme",Trusted_Connection = "No")

#set the cursor for table_one
cursor = table_one_connection.cursor()
cursor.execute("[data].[Tableschema].[DEFINED_SP] @start_date='xx-xx-xx', @end_date='xx-xx-xx'")

#Fetching data
cursor.fetchall()

#Create the workbook of results
print("Generating the workbooks with the database data")
cursor_results_workbook   = xlwt.Workbook()
results_sheet             = cursor_results_workbook.add_sheet("SP values")

#row counter that you use to move from rows
row_counter = 0

#write the data onto the Excel file
for index,value in enumerate(cursor):
    try:
        #extract from the tuple 'results' the value of each item and store it in every column for all rows
        results_sheet.write(row_counter, 0, value[0])
        results_sheet.write(row_counter, 1, value[1])
        results_sheet.write(row_counter, 2, value[2])
        results_sheet.write(row_counter, 3, value[3])
        results_sheet.write(row_counter, 4, value[4])
    except:
        print("Error in line %s\n data=%s" % (index, value))
    row_counter = row_counter + 1

cursor.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit the following to split `row string` into `column values`:

```
for index, value in enumerate(table_one_connection_results):
    results_sheet.write(row_table_one,0,value)
```

to

```
for index, value in enumerate(table_one_connection_results):
    for col, col_value in enumerate(value.split(',')):
        try:
            results_sheet.write(row_table_one, col, col_value)
        except:
            print('Error in line %s, column %s\ndata=%s' % (index, col, table_one_connection_results[index]) )
```

Used Documentation: [xlwt API Reference](http://xlwt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html)

Comment: hello @stovfl, your suggestion worked and now I was able to detect why the Exception error occurred but now when the loop tries to write into the Excel file I get that all lines have an error. Any other suggestion?

Comment: @AlejandroRamos: Updated my Answer